# wget in AWS could formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, wget

I'm using wget to fetch jar during the deployment in CI process. WGET command doesn't execute after executing the cloudformation command for the AWS service. Before couldformation command it works fine. If i change the wget to curl, then its WORKS fine. Not sure what could be the issue. Please give some suggestions

Answer (score 0):

`wget` might not be installed on the instance by default. Make sure your CloudFormation template installs it before trying to use it.

Comment: The cloud formation script and the wget is being executed from same unix box. I'm not facing this problem in the  created instance. I'm facing this problem from creating controller Unix box.